# Is my approach correct in solving for subspace and finding dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{m} \in V$; Let $U$={$c_{1}v_{1}+,...+c_{m}v_{m}:c_{1},...c_{m}\in \mathbb{R}$ and $c_{1}+..+c_{m}$=0}. Is $U$ a subspace of $V$. What is the dimension of $U$?

my attempt for finding dimension of $U$ :: $c_{1}$ can be written in terms of $c_{2},..c_{m}$ and substituting $c_{1}$ in the above equation we can express $U$ as linear combination of $v_{2}-v{1},...,v_{m}-v_{1}$ so dimension of $U$ is $m-1$ is this right or is there a case where $dim(U)<m-1$? And also what happens if $c_{1}+..+c_{m}=1$, Is $U$ even a subspace for this case?
**EDIT** In the above case i assumed $v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{m}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: It's an excellent approach... **if** ... $\;v_1,...,v_m\;$ are linearly independent. Otherwise $\;U\;$ still is a subspace but we can't tell what its dimension is.

Comment: @DonAntonio So, you are saying $dim(U) \leqq m-1$

Comment: @hrithikmahesh When you say, "Is U even a subspace for this case", do you mean the case when $\sum c_i = 1$ or you mean the case presented in the initial problem?

Comment: @hrithikmahesh Indeed so, in any case.

Comment: @E.Nole for $\Sigma c_{i} =1 $

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks for conforming.

Comment: I think for the case where $\sum c_i = 1$ we cannot guarantee that the $\vec 0$ vector will be in the span of $U$. Therefore, $U$ will not always be a subspace.

Comment: @DonAntonio can you comment on $\sum c_{i} =1$ case?

Comment: @E.Nole take $c_{1} = c_{2} = 0.5$ and $v_{1} = -v{2}$ and $c_{3}=c{4}=..=0$ case $\vec 0$ will be there in this case .

Comment: @hrithikmahesh Your post says you are assuming the vectors f $U$ are linearly independent. So you can't have that $v_1 = -v_2$. And even if you remove that restriction, providing one example does not guarantee that $\mathbf{0}$ will be in the span of $U$ for $\textbf{all}$ cases in which $\sum c_i = 1$ .

Comment: @E.Nole ok, that clarifies for me

Comment: As an example, consider $U = \{v_1, v_2 :  v_1 \neq v_2 \space \& \space v_1, v_2 \neq \vec 0 \}$. Define $c_1 = 5, c_2 = -4$. If wlog $5v_1 + -4v_2 \neq 0$ Then there's no way to express the zero vector in such a way that the sum of the coefficients equals 1.

Comment: @hrithikmahesh In that case you clearly have not a subspace: just multiply any such linear combination by a scalar different of $\;1\;$ ...say, zero.

Comment: @hrithikmahesh Also [see this](https://yutsumura.com/the-subspace-of-linear-combinations-whose-sums-of-coefficients-are-zero/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your interested:

**Theorem**: Let be $\;\phi:V\to\Bbb F\;$ a linear functional from a linear space $\;V\;$ to the definition field $\;\Bbb F\;$ . If $\;\phi\neq0\;$ , then $\;\ker\phi\;$ is a maximal subspace of $\;V\;$ . In the finite dimensional case, say $\;\dim V=n<\infty\;$ , this means $\;\dim\ker\phi=n-1\;$ .

The above is not so hard to prove with Zorn's Lemma (or the dimension theorem in the finite dimensional case).

Now in your question: the map $\;\phi:\text{Span}\,\{v_1,...,v_m\}\to\Bbb F\;$ defined by

$$\phi\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_kv_k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^m a_k$$

is a linear map and thus a linear functional, so $\;U=\ker\phi\;$ is always a subspace of $\;V\;$ . In case $\;\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ are linearly independent then $\;\dim\ker\phi=m-1\;$ , and in case $\;\{v_1,...,v_m\}\;$ is a basis of $\;V\;$ then $\;U=\ker\phi\;$ is a maximal subspace of $\;V\;$ .